# Extending a class and making the propeties required

Tags: typescript, class

There are 2 classes that share part of the code, so I created a `Common` class.

One of the children classes needs all those properties as required, my idea was to use the **Required** utility type.

Something like this:

```
class A extends Common {
  //...
 }

class B extends Required<Common> {
  //...
 }
```

But I get the error that Required isn't defined. Is there a simple way to achieve what I am looking for (if it is convoluted I will just change the code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `extends Common`, and make the properties required using `implements`:

```
class Common {
  foo?: string;
  bar?: number;
}

class A extends Common {
  //...
 }

class B extends Common implements Required<Common> {
  constructor(
    public foo: string,
    public bar: number,
  ) {
    super();
  }
 }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbR8B20DeBYAUNaAZvPAPwBc0EALgE4CWqA5gNy74BGYN50qAronYBTGqxwBfXLlCQYAQWhCAHlSGoAJjATI0mNtAD0BgHSm2knNPBRoAIUUq1muEhTo6iAA4ghiNVRgAJSEARz46GiF1AB5tNwA+PTxoYDRqGj5gKngaAAp9fE8+dhA6YEJiCnSGRgAaAugikrLoThoKfkEReuSASiT8fAg+TxFc3rF8C2hxIA)

Comment: Great, thank you. Have to wait to accept.